# A question about IoT Core (MQTT) data integrity and service guarantees

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

I'm looking at using AWS IoT Core as our data ingress for various types of devices. One of the unbreakable rules of our old ingress pipeline is data integrity. When a device has sent data into our backend, the data does not get lost (it's written to permanent storage before we ack to the device that we've received the data).

In MQTT things seem a bit different. From what I've read so far, if a device writes to an MQTT topic, it has the option of setting QoS to 0 (at most once) or 1 (at least once) and to guarantee delivery we would pick QoS 1 of course.

However, to the best of my understanding, that doesn't guarantee that there is any subscriber on the topic to pick the message up. If a device sends a message to a topic with no subscriber, the message will get lost. MQTT has a concept of retained messages (which AWS supports since about a year ago) but that only retains the latest message, so if a device sends two messages to a non-subscribed topic, the first message will be lost.

So now for my actual question (finally). AWS IoT has "rules" that you can attach to MQTT topics. However, I have not found any information about what guarantees AWS IoT provides that these rules will always be monitoring the topics they're created on. Can anyone tell me whether there is a 100% guarantee that a message sent to an MQTT topic that has a rule assigned to it will not ever get lost? By that I mean that I need that rule to finish processing and either successfully execute the actions defined on it or successfully execute the error action defined on it (which would just be writing the message to a DLQ, either SQS or S3 bucket).

Answer (score 1):

I personally never heard about data loss caused by a AWS IoT Rule.
This is just a simple message forwarding. I had a project where we had to forward about thousand messages per second to other services with these rules. We had some data loss, but not caused by the rules, but:

- Edge device did not send the message (kind of rejected)
- Wrong handling of a specific kind of message in the transformation process
- Duplicates (data is also not plausible) - Can be handled with SQS
- Quotas: very important if You have a high load to check the quotas. If the quota is being hit the ingest may fail silently.

At the end of the day we had several problems with IoT Core including Greengrass and we switched to Kinesis Data Streams and Kinesis Delivery Streams, where we had more control. Edge device was configured for retries in case ingest failed and we didn't reached the quotas with autoscaling option on. There were also no duplicates received.
Keep in mind that this is only my project experiance, Your case is probably very different and the IoT Rules could be actually a valid approach for You.